# Tool to list users who accessed a particular file and when

Tags: windows, security, filesystems

In windows I can look at the Last Access time of a file and it will show me when the file has been touched last time. Is there any tool which could give me the list of the users who accessed a particular file and when did they did that. Basically I have a file on a network drive and I would like to have some kind of basic audit reporting tool.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate tool, Windows is already capable of doing that (works very similar for other versions of Windows):

> **[How to audit user access of files, folders, and printers in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399)**